# Make a module use a derived class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, module, project

I'm trying to extend a modules functionality.  The module includes a class (`BaseContainer`) that contains as a member instances of another class (`BaseObject`) in the same module.  I want to extend both classes.  But the `BaseContainer` seems to be using the `BaseObject` instead of the extended derived object.

EDIT: tried restructuring the project.  Same result

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar/
        __init.py__
            from .BaseModule import BaseObject
            from .BaseModule import BaseContainer
```

> BaseModule.py

```
           class BaseObject:
               def __init__(self):
                   self.aMember = True

           class BaseContainer:
               def __init__(self):
                   self.myObject = BaseObject()
```

> DerivedModule.py

```
from . import BaseModule

class DerivedObject(BaseModule.BaseObject):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseObject.__init__(self)
        self.derivedMember = True

class DerivedContainer(BaseContainer):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseContainer.__init__(self)
        Other code
```

But if I instantiate a `DerivedContainer`, it's `myObject` has no `derivedMember`.

I'm not surprised by this outcome, it would make sense that the base module has no idea about `DerivedContainer`.  But is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of `DerivedModule.py` add:

```
BaseModule.BaseObject = DerivedObject
```

**Note**:  If you do this then other modules will also get `DerivedObject` and not `BaseObject`.